# Is there any way to handle memory usage in read_edgelist of networkx in python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, networkx

I use read_edgelist function of networkx to read a graph's edges from a file(500Mb), G(nodes= 2.3M, edges=33M), it uses the whole memory of machine and seems nothing it does after not finding more memory to load whole graph. 
Is there any way to handle this problem like sparse graph solution or using other libraries?

Comment: To directly answer your question: yes, there are ways to handle this using either of the approaches you mention. If you want recommendations about particular techniques, that's outside of the scope of SO.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkX uses a sparse representation; and `read_edgelist` reads the file line by line (ie. it does not load the whole file at once).

So if NetworkX uses too much memory, it means this is actually what it takes to represent the whole graph in memory.

A possible solution is to read the file yourself and discard as much edges as possible before feeding it to NetworkX.